# jQuery code folding plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-plugins

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin that does code folding of XML structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Treeview](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/) plugin might work for you. If you could parse your XML to a `<ul>`, it should do the job.